# Created a 30 day trial today, verified my phone number via email, but now I cant log into the lightning experience!

Tags: lightning, trailhead, logging

Im having a real hard time understanding what Im doing wrong here. 
I have signed up for a 15 day trial, and a 30 day trial, but I am not able to log back into either of these accounts. I linked them with my phone number and verified but something must be happening that I am really confused about. I AM typing the correct password that I used to sign up with, and seemingly the correct username, which is the email they created for the account. Yet I am unable to log in, and I try the "forgot my password" button but I never get an email sent to me about resetting my password for either account, including the 30 day trial account I created today! Please help!

Comment: Which domain are you using to log in?  login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com?

Comment: Did you change the My Domain configuration in the ORG?

Comment: @KoenCertyn I realized I was using a URL from my trail head playground, and I just logged out and tried to log in as a different user. So I switched to login.salesforce.com and I am now able to log in to any SF account I created, Thank you!!!!

Comment: @GlenDeMarcos no, but I think I figured out the issue, see my comment to Koen :D thank you for the response!